# Does blue shade conserve battery life

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire

**I'm at forty percent battery life and I need to know if blue shade conserves battery life**

Answer (score 2):

For non-AMOLED devices, the battery consumption of the screen is solely (?) determined by the brightness - the content displayed, be it full black or full white, doesn't matter. Adding a blue filter won't change that either. If anything, the existence of the app itself may introduce a slight *increase* in battery consumption.

Comment: Absolutely correct